# Is it possible to migrate a google VM instance from one account to another keeping its external IP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, ip, virtual-machine, pyinstaller

I am working in a python project that interacts both with the cloud and with an USB port. I hardcoded the VM IP in my python code, but I need to migrate the server from my personal account to the company's account. Because I deployed this python project as a .exe I have to build it again (with pyinstaller) in case I change the server IP. Is it possible to keep this IP after migrating?

Comment: You cannot move Google Cloud owned IP addresses between accounts. Google Cloud support might offer that ability, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [Bring your own ip is possible](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/bring-your-own-ip)

Answer (score 0):

Best security practice, don't always keep public IP.
Internal/external IP identified with DNS server. Understand the objective and decide accordingly.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't keep the same IP from one project to another one (or you are very lucky). However, in this case, I recommend you to perform that:

- [Replace your billing account with the company billing account](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#change_the_billing_account_for_a_project)
- [Migrate the project from your organization to the company organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration)

Instead of recreate your project, simply change the ownership.

---

In the future, follow subbu recommendation: use domain name instead of IP!

Answer (score 0):

I would first like to address that, for **transferring and/or keeping public IP addresses from VM instances**, you will need to then review the following [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) on reserving static external IP addresses, as an external IP address is the public IP address.

In your case, since you have public IP’s assigned to the VMs, you will need to then **promote an ephemeral external IP address to a static external IP address**; here you’ll find the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) that demonstrates how to do this as well. This is how you can keep a public IP address for your instances.

Please keep in mind that, to preserve the same IPs after copying your VMs, you can do that **if the instance is created in the same zone**, so the new instance in the new project should be created in the same zone.

Moreover, in terms of moving VMs from one project to another, it is not possible, as VMs are binded to the project that they are located in. If you would like to move VMs from one organization to another, you will need to **move the entire project to the end organization**. You can follow this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/project-migration) to learn more about migration.