# How can I migrate a google VM instance from one account to another

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine, migrate

Me and my colleague have a two independent google accounts. If possible, I want to migrate one of my VM instance into his account, where he can start using it with the disk that contains the applications and operating system needed to start the `VM` that I want to migrate.

- On my account, I have created a custom image and afterwards I give an `Owner` permission to my college's account using `IAM & Admin`.
- Then my college(from different google account) created an `Instance` by using the custom image under `My First Project` section. But when he connected into created instance, its home directory was empty even its created from the custom image that I created from my disk.

`Boot Disk` => `Custom Images` => `Select my shared Project` => `Selected the Custom Image that is created on my shared Project` => `Create`

I observe that even I was able to create a image from different project, its contents was not migrated.

I was wondering is it possible to migrate a google VM instance from one account to another? If yes, how can I do it?

Related:

- [Is it possible to migrate a google VM instance from one account to another keeping its external IP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69801549/is-it-possible-to-migrate-a-google-vm-instance-from-one-account-to-another-keepi)

Comment: The home directory is based upon the username. Are you using the same credentials to login? Look under the **/home** directory.

Comment: @JohnHanley Username was different due to different e-mail address that is used. I am able to see my files under `/home` directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest creating a snapshot of your VM's boot disk. Then create an image from that snapshot and share it with your colleague.

As John Hanley pointed out in the comments to your question, you might be looking in the wrong place! Google will create separate user home directories based on the username.